# Sequence Converging to Supremum

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Show if $C$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which has a supremum $\alpha$, then there is a sequence $(c_n)$ from $C$ which converges to $\alpha$.

So far I have by definition of a supremum, for each $\epsilon$ > 0 there is a c $\in$ C such that $\alpha$ - $\epsilon$ < c. But how do I work this into a sequence?

Comment: I started by considering a closed set which would contain $\alpha$ then the sequence is trivial. So if $C$ is an open set I believe the solution has something again to do with limit points but I'm not sure.

Comment: What does it mean that $\alpha$ is a supremum of $C?$ Assume $\alpha$ is not in $C.$

Comment: $alpha$ is $\geq$ all x $\in C$

Comment: No, that's not what it means. For example if $C=(0, 1),$ then $10$ is not equal to $\sup C.$

Comment: $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $C$ and for all $x$ that are upper bounds for $C$, $\alpha$ $\leq$ $x$

Comment: Think about what this means: Is it possible that there is no $c\in C$ such that $\alpha - c < 1/2?$

Comment: Would it be possible to construct a sequence that is an open ball around $\alpha$ that slowly converges to $\alpha$, for example $N_\frac{1}{n}(\alpha)$

Answer (score 1):

Set $c_n$ to be a $c\in C$ that corresponds to $\alpha-\frac{1}{n}\leq c\leq \alpha$

Then by sandwhich it converges

Comment: Not "the" but "a" though